# can't install swm on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, compiling, libraries, make

I apologize if this has already been asked I couldn't find any solutions online, I am trying to install swm from [here](https://github.com/dcat/swm), but i keep getting this error when running make in terminal

> c99 swm.o -o swm -lxcb -L/opt/X11/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib
>   swm.o: In function `cleanup':
>   swm.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to`xcb_disconnect'
>   swm.o: In function `deploy':
>   swm.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to`xcb_connect'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `xcb_connection_has_error'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to`xcb_get_setup'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `xcb_setup_roots_iterator'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to`xcb_grab_button'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `xcb_grab_button'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x145): undefined reference to`xcb_change_window_attributes_checked'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to `xcb_flush'
>   swm.o: In function`focus':
>   swm.c:(.text+0x1ba): undefined reference to `xcb_get_geometry'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x1d2): undefined reference to`xcb_get_geometry_reply'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x4d1): undefined reference to `xcb_generate_id'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x52f): undefined reference to`xcb_create_pixmap'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x53e): undefined reference to `xcb_generate_id'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x561): undefined reference to`xcb_create_gc'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x586): undefined reference to `xcb_change_gc'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x5a7): undefined reference to`xcb_poly_fill_rectangle'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x5dd): undefined reference to `xcb_change_gc'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x5fe): undefined reference to`xcb_poly_fill_rectangle'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x625): undefined reference to `xcb_change_window_attributes'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x639): undefined reference to`xcb_free_pixmap'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x64d): undefined reference to `xcb_free_gc'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x675): undefined reference to`xcb_set_input_focus'
>   swm.o: In function `subscribe':
>   swm.c:(.text+0x6fd): undefined reference to`xcb_change_window_attributes'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x722): undefined reference to `xcb_configure_window'
>   swm.o: In function`events_loop':
>   swm.c:(.text+0x765): undefined reference to `xcb_wait_for_event'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x807): undefined reference to`xcb_kill_client'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x858): undefined reference to `xcb_map_window'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x8c8): undefined reference to`xcb_configure_window'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x8dc): undefined reference to `xcb_get_geometry'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x8f4): undefined reference to`xcb_get_geometry_reply'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x957): undefined reference to `xcb_warp_pointer'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x9aa): undefined reference to`xcb_warp_pointer'
>   swm.c:(.text+0x9ee): undefined reference to `xcb_grab_pointer'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xa01): undefined reference to`xcb_flush'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xa20): undefined reference to `xcb_query_pointer'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xa38): undefined reference to`xcb_query_pointer_reply'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xa5c): undefined reference to `xcb_get_geometry'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xa74): undefined reference to`xcb_get_geometry_reply'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xbce): undefined reference to `xcb_configure_window'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xbdd): undefined reference to`xcb_flush'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xc02): undefined reference to `xcb_get_geometry'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xc1a): undefined reference to`xcb_get_geometry_reply'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xc72): undefined reference to `xcb_configure_window'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xc81): undefined reference to`xcb_flush'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xca8): undefined reference to `xcb_ungrab_pointer'
>   swm.c:(.text+0xcf8): undefined reference to`xcb_flush'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:18: recipe for target 'swm' failed
>   make: *** [swm] Error 1

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I got it! You need to change line 19 in `Makefile` to

```
        @${LD} -o $@ ${OBJ} ${LDFLAGS}
```

Comment: dosn't work, I have the same problem and the package is installed.

Comment: Ok, I will go back in my hole now :)

Comment: Try it now that I have added all the other headers

Comment: I'am not JeffMontes ;) But sorry, no, same error.

Comment: Try now @A.B. Now it will get all the packages matching `libxcb*-dev`

Comment: Great, it works

Comment: @A.B. Glad I could help! I'm making a pull request right now!

Comment: @JeffMontes Could you please mark this as the answer if it helped?

Comment: O.K. The pull request was merged! (Yay!)

Comment: @JeffMontes any feedback?